# System.Timers.Timer massively inaccurate

Tags: c#, multithreading, foreach, timer, parallel.foreach

I've written a program which uses all available cores by using `Parallel.ForEach`. The list for the `ForEach` contains ~1000 objects and the computation for each object take some time (~10 sec).
In this scenario I setup a timer like this:

```
timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
timer.Elapsed += TimerHandler;
timer.Interval = 15000;
timer.Enabled = true;

private void TimerHandler(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + ": Timer fired");
}
```

At the moment the `TimerHandler` method is a stub to make sure the problem isn't caused by this method.

My expectation was that the `TimerHandler` method will be executed every ~15 seconds. However, the time between two calls to this method even reaches 40 seconds, so 25 seconds too much.
By using `new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount -1 }` for the `Parallel.ForEach` method this doesn't happen and the expected interval of 15 seconds is seen.

Is it intended that I have to make sure that there is always one core available per active timer? Seems to be a bit odd even more, because the "reserved" could be a valuable resource for my computation.

Edit: As indicated by Yuval setting a fixed minimum of threads in the pool by `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads` solved the problem. I also tried `new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount }` (so without the `-1` in the initial question) for the `Parallel.ForEach` method and this also solves the problem. However, I have no good explanation why these modifications solved the problem. Maybe there were so many threads created that the timer thread just got "lost" for a "long" time until it was executed again.

Comment: If you explicitly set the number of threads in the thread-pool before executing the parallel loop, does this still happen? (Using `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads`)

Comment: are you pegging processor usage when you use all processors? if so, all events will respond slower due to how windows processes the message pump.

Comment: I suspect the thread running the parallel threads (which is probably the same thread running the timer) is blocking itself. If you can find a way to run your timer on a different thread, your problem might go away. The thread running your timer might be different depending on how your app is hosted btw (e.g. Windows forms vs console app)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov That seems to work, thank you. I've set it to a fixed value (tried 50 even if I have only 4 cores) and it works. I also tried to set `new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount }` (so without the `-1`) and it has the same effect.

Comment: Problem solved - explanation please?  Why would setting this fix the problem, regardless of what the value is set to?

Comment: The fact that the thread-pool initializes with `Environment.ProcessorCount` is what made me think of that. The thread-pool is probably starved.

Comment: @Atoms I have a console application and yes the thread which calls the foreach also calls the timer. I checked your assumption by putting the timer commands in a task from the task factory. The problem remains the same which seems to be logical as the documentation for the timer class indicates that the timer is already executed in its own thread.

Comment: @user2653422 thank you for the followup. I'll remember that if I ever see this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The `Parallel` class uses an internal TPL facility called self replicating tasks. They are meant to consume all available thread resources. I don't know what kind of limits are in place but it seems that it's all-consuming. I have answered basically the same question a few days ago.

The `Parallel` class is prone to spawn insane amounts of tasks without any limit. It is easy to provoke it to literally spawn unlimited threads (2 per second). I consider the `Parallel` class unusable without a manually specified max-DOP. It is a time bomb that explodes in production randomly under load.

`Parallel` is especially poisonous in ASP.NET scenarios where many requests share one thread-pool.

**Update:** I forgot to make the key point. Timer ticks are queued to the thread pool. If the pool is saturated they get in line and execute at a later time. (This is the reason why timer ticks can happen concurrently or after timers are stopped.) This explains what you are seeing. The way to fix that is to fix the pool overloading.

The best fix for this particular scenario would be a custom task scheduler with a fixed amount of threads. `Parallel` can be made to use that task scheduler. The Parallel Extension Extras have such a scheduler. Get that work off the globally shared thread pool. Normally, I would recomment PLINQ but that is not able to take a scheduler. In a sense both Parallel and PLINQ are needlessly crippled APIs.

Don't use `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads`. Don't mess with global process wide settings. Just leave the poor thread pool alone.

Also, don't use `Environment.ProcessorCount -1` because that wastes one core.

> the timer is already executed in its own thread

The timer is a data structure in the OS kernel. There is no thread until a tick must be queued. Not sure how exactly that works but the tick is queued to the thread pool in .NET eventually. *That's* when the problem starts.

As a solution you *could* start a thread that sleeps in a loop in order to simulate a timer. That's a hack, though, because it does not fix the root cause: The overloaded thread pool.